# Is there a method to add custom device without re-compiling QEMU?

Tags: qemu, qemu-device

Hi I'm in a project to develop driver and software for a chip.

However, the testing resource is limited, thus I would like to make a custom device on a virtual machine so that I can develop without a real chip or board.

I'm not familiar with QEMU's source code but I googled some [methods](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/implementing-custom-qemu-pci-device-nikos-mouzakitis/), while most of them is using need to re-compile QEMU.

Thus I would like to ask if there is a way to add a specific device (assuming it as PCIe) that do not need to re-compile QMEU? Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, QEMU does not currently provide a mechanism for adding device models other than "write your model as part of QEMU and build a QEMU binary from it".

Remember also that because QEMU is under the GPL license this means that the device model you build into it will also be covered by the GPL when built into that final binary; you should make sure you understand what your obligations will be as a result.